# How to make a custom border on a Windows form in VS 2017

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

How do programs like Photoshop and even Visual Studio have custom borders with custom minimize/expand/close buttons along with the ability to drag the window around and snap it like a normal window?
I'm having a lot of trouble finding how this can be done in a C# Windows form.

[image]

Comment: It has been known for years that you should either write your own custom controls, or use a third party set, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hws6h2t(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Windows Forms is very limited when it comes to customizing existing controls. You should use WPF.